# How to get a fully qualified class name from class alias

Tags: python, python-3.x

File has an import:

```py
from lxml import etree
```

or with alias

```py
from lxml import etree as tree
```

How to get `lxml.etree` by using just `something(etree)` and `something(tree)`?

Same question goes to go deeper how to get `lxml.etree._Element` by using just `something(etree._Element)` and `something(tree._Element)`?

It could be used for easier construction of error messages on validation of correct argument type of a function.

Example:

```py
if isinstance(xml_doc, etree._Element):
        expected_type = something(etree._Element)
        msg = f'Expected {expected_type}, received {type(xml_doc)}'
        raise TypeError(msg)
```

In PHP it would be `::class`.

**Update:** A new problem is: `etree._Element` is a protected member and should not be accessed directly. Complaint by lint.

```
Access to a protected member _Element of a client class (protected-access)
```

Comment: It's not clear what error messages would need to refer to a particular library in use. The user shouldn't care if you are using `lxml` or some other XML library.

Comment: The stdlib's `inspect` module will give you quite a lot of informations on most objects. Now I'd suggest that in Python, "validation of correct argument type of a function" is most often just counterproductive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering `etree` is a class, you can get the class name using this:

```
from lxml import etree as tree

print(tree.__name__)
```

Comment: `lxml.etree` is a module. This still works, but I think you confused [Axe319](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59412939/4518341) :P

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto Dhaliwhal's answer you can also get the module with `tree.__module__`

Edit: This might have to be programmed by the module in order to function. I just tried it on tkinter since I didn't have that module installed.

Edit 2: I just installed lxml and as Bruno pointed out, that's the case. My fault for not testing with the proper module. ;)
Example:

```
from tkinter import Label as lb
print(lb.__module__)
```

Comment: I tried `print(tree.__module__)` but got `AttributeError: module 'lxml.etree' has no attribute '__module__'`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @wjandrea `lxml.etree` is a module, so it doesn't have a `__module__` attribute (wouldn't  make much sense).

Comment: @bruno Ah yeah I got it to work on a class: `from typing import List as L; print(L.__module__)  # -> typing`.